# How to add multiple bubbles on maps using jHERE jQuery

Tags: jquery, here-api

I am trying to add multiple bubbles on maps using jHERE jQuery (http://jhere.net/).
I tried use this code:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
$('#mapContainer').jHERE({zoom: 5});
  $('#mapContainer').jHERE('bubble', [52.500556, 13.398889], {closable: false, content: 'Abc: 100'});
  $('#mapContainer').jHERE('bubble', [51.500556, 13.398889], {closable: false, content: 'Def: 100'});
});
```

[image: maps]

But only one / last bubble generated on the maps.
How to add multiple bubbles on maps?

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

By default the `autoClose`-option of the InfoBubbles-component is set to `true`(only a single InfoBubble may be open at a time).

You must set this option to `false`.

Add this after the creation of the map, but before the creation of the InfoBubbles:

```
  $('#mapContainer').jHERE('originalMap', 
                           function(map,here){
                            var b=new here.map.component.InfoBubbles();
                            map.addComponent(b);
                            b.options.set("autoClose", false);});
```

Demo: http://bin.jhere.net/c0b57694d70d50840528